# Include js in cakephp in <select> menu

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have this code in cakephp 1.2:

```
<select onchange="if(this.value.match('Convegni')) {
                     document.getElementById('menu3').style.display = 'block'; } 
                  else { document.getElementById('menu3').style.display = 'none'; }" >
            [...]
        </select><br />
```

Now, since I have different cases to check (Convegni, Corsi, ecc) I want to write this script on a file and include it in onchange=""; 
I think I should put it in webroot/js folder, but I can't go ahead from there.

Answer (score 0):

You would create the file in webroot/js.  I will use menu_match.js as an example.  The code inside should be formatted like the following (essentially the same, except you need to name the function however you will call it later).

```
function menu_match()
{
   if(this.value.match('Convegni')) {
     document.getElementById('menu3').style.display = 'block'; } 
   else { document.getElementById('menu3').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Then in your view you will need to include a link to this js file:

```
<?php echo($javascript->link("des_toggle_gen_drug.js")); ?>
```

and then you'll need to change your select to reference the function instead of the actual code.

```
<select onchange="return menu_match()"   .....   </select>
```

Comment: you may need 

'return true;'

at the very end of the function.

Comment: Tried it too, but it's not changing

Comment: Try putting an alert('test'); before the if, alert('if'); in the if statement, and an alert(else); in the else statement.  This will tell you if your even making it into the function.